# Tournure « quitte que je quitte » ?

Tags: oral, syntaxe

J'ai trouvé cette tournure dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I :*

> **Quitte que je quitte** la Butte que c'est devenu plus que vampires...
> qui démordent pas de me saigner blanc... j'irai attendre à Saint-Malo
> !...

Par le contexte, j'imagine que le narrateur veut dire « Il faut que je quitte la Butte ».

Mais, je ne comprends pas très  bien cette syntaxe. Pourriez-vous m'aider à la décortiquer ? S-agit-il d'une tournure plutôt de l'oral ?

Answer (score 1):

Céline a habité la Butte Montmartre, [(Avenue) rue Gaveneau](http://louisferdinandceline.free.fr/romans/feerie/ferresu.htm) , alias [rue Girardon](http://www.lepetitcelinien.com/2011/03/louis-ferdinand-celine-4-rue-girardon.html).

Il semble donc que « quitte que je quitte » soit du « Célinien » pour « quitte à ce que je quitte ».

[image]

Comment: Merci, LPH. Je ne connaissais pas cette expression.