# Un autre impératif ?

Tags: syntaxe

Hier, j'ai posé [une question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52749/tournure-quitte-que-je-quitte) sur une tournure que j'avais trouvée dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* : « quitte que je quitte ».

User @LPH gentiment a répondu que, selon lui, il s'agit d'une variation de « quitte à ce que je quitte ».

Tout de même, j'avais déjà trouvé une tournure pareille dans *Journal d'un curé de campagne* de Bernanos :

> La malheureuse passait ses nuits à quatre pattes entre son seau et sa
> wassingue - **arrose que j'arrose** - tellement que la mousse commençait
> de grimper le long des colonnes, l'herbe poussait dans les joints des
> dalles.

Donc, il s'agit d'une construction classique pour indiquer l'impératif ? Pourriez-vous m'expliquer cette syntaxe dans « arrose que j'arrose » ?

Comment: Dans "arrose que j'arrose", le verbe arrose est utilisé 2 fois, comme dans vaille qui vaille ou coute que coute. Par contre, dans quitte à ce que je quitte, le premier quitte à veut dirre "au risque de" différent du sens du verbe quitter .

Comment: @Graffito Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

Dans "arrose que j'arrose" le sens est différent, et il n'est pas question d'assimiler cette tournure à "arrose à ce que j'arrose", qui ne signifie rien. Voilà ce que LBU explique à propos de la personne du verbe.

> (LBU 14<sup>e</sup> édition,  § 655 1°)
>
> **Au singulier**, la première personne désigne le locuteur ou le
> scripteur, celui qui parle ou qui écrit.
> • JE suis socialiste, mais, en tant que président de la République, j'ai à respecter ceux qui ne le sont pas (Fr. MITTERRAND, déclaration citée dans le Monde, 28 juin 1985). — JE n'écrirai pas de poème d'acquiescement (CHAR, Feuillets d'Hypnos,
> 114).
>
> Dans la littérature romanesque, la 1<sup>re</sup> personne ne doit pas nécessairement être assimilée à l'auteur du récit : la fiction peut aussi concerner cet aspect.
> Par l'effet d'une syntaxe affective, la première personne est parfois substituée à la 2e et même à la 3e (dans ce cas, cela peut concerner des choses, rendues ainsi plus présentes, plus actives).
>
> Une mère, par ex., dira à son enfant : Est-ce que j'aime toujours les bonbons ?
> (Le ton indiquant que le je est ici un tu.)
> • La malheureuse passait ses nuits à
> quatre pattes entre son seau et sa wassingue [= serpillière] - arrose que J'arrose -
> tellement que la mousse commençait de grimper le long des colonnes (BERNANOS,
> Journal d'un curé de camp., Pl., p. 1038).
> • Il pleuvait dessus à grands flots... [...]
> Et que JE te pleus des pleines cascades... (CÉLINE, Mort à crédit, F°, p. 605.)

Autrement, il n'y a pas de syntaxe particulière dont se soucier : c'est une construction figée. Le sens est dans ce contexte « elle n'arrêtait pas d'arroser », « elle arrosait tant et plus ».